# The connection was reset

Tags: magento-1.7, php

I am having a problem with some of my Magento websites. I get the message "The connection was reset" in Firefox or "No data received" in Chrome, while my other sites (custom build PHP sites) are working perfectly. This happens time by time (for example once in a while, like 4 to 5 days)

I have searched for apache log error but there is nothing strange there.

I have been using APC for cache and i tried without it but after some time i get this error again and it is solved only by restarting the Apache server.

Environment information:
Linux 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 03:15:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 running CentOS
PHP Hander: DSO (because i am using APC)
PHP Version 5.4.24
Apache 2.4 (already had the 2.2 but the same problem)
Intel® Core™ i7-920 Quad-Core
48 GB DDR3 RAM

UPDATE: This problem happens only with Magento 1.7, i have and a 1.8 Magento site in the same server but it works fine when the other site has this problem.

I don't really understand what can cause this problem.

Comment: Can you check what are the processes related to PHP running when you get the error?

Comment: @Emi i have to wait for the error to occur again :/

Comment: The error might be caused by the fact that some cron is running, that would set locks on the mysql tables. So you should look for the running processes and then see what they are doing.

Comment: what is your environment? which versions of php,apache, which OS, do you use php as apache module, via cgi or via fcgi? if fcgi, managed by a apache module or php own solution?

Is there anything in the apache error logs? For example a segfault?

Comment: If a restart of Apache fixes your issue, the culprit is absolutely Apache. Check to make sure your config settings are correct. It should also throw a log in your Apache logs at the exact time of the event. To me it sounds like a timeout/termination is happening to an open/running Apache process.

Comment: @Flyingmana i just updated the environment specification.

Comment: @MarkShust i thought so but the other Magento 1.8 sill keeps working after the 1.7 version stops and shows these messages. In the apache log file there is no any error information in the time that the problem is occurred.

Comment: If nothing is in the logs, there is either no problem or not enough logging.
Iam pretty sure, you should have a segfault error in some of the logs.  

Are you sure without APC the Problem still exists? Anyway, the combination APC+PHP5.4 is dangerous, as it is unstable. You should update to PHP5.5 as soon as possible or look how to install the ZendOpCache for 5.4

Comment: @Flyingmana it still happens after i remove the APC configuration from Magento, now i just disabled APC at all form php.ini so it's not running. The PHP 5.5.9 is marked as experimental in WHM that's why i have not installed it. I am using WHM and i am checking error logs of apache in /usr/local/apache/logs error_logs and /usr/local/apache/domlogs for the specified domain. I will have a look again.

Comment: WHM -- are you running on a shared host? Most likely you are running out of memory if that is the case. If so, I'd get on a decent hosting account first then go from there.

Comment: @MarkShust as mentioned in the post the server is dedicated and it has Intel® Core™ i7-920 Quad-Core 48 GB DDR3 RAM so i don't think that could be the problem

Comment: Have a look through http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429 and see if any of these debugging tips help you find out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Set in the php.ini file:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Then restart Apache. If you are getting a blank page, the error should definitely be logged.